# How to extrapolate a changed value from a tkinter checkbox?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having trouble establishing how to retrieve the value of a checkbox variable properly. I also wish to ask whether the code;

```
onvalue=1, offvalue=0
```

Is redundant.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
mGui=Tk()
checkCmd=IntVar()
checkCmd.set(0)
def runSelectedItems():
    if checkCmd == 0:
        labelText = Label(text="It worked").pack()
    else:
        labelText = Label(text="It did not").pack()

checkBox1 = Checkbutton(mGui, variable=checkCmd, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text="Command  Prompt").pack()
buttonCmd = Button(mGui, text="Run Checked Items", command=runSelectedItems).pack()
```

Comment: Do you mean "extrapolate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IntVar` is a special type of variable in that you have so fetch the value explicitly with `get()`:

```
if checkCmd.get() == 1:
```

You don't need:

```
onvalue=1, offvalue=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm)

*offvalue =*
The value corresponding to a non-checked button. **The default is 0.**

*onvalue =*
The value corresponding to a checked button. **The default is 1.**

In other words, yes... it is redundant. I would try bookmarking the effbot website because it is really useful for learning tkinter with Python and then you don't have to wait for answers from us. Although would not have gotten the advice from *figbeam*.

Comment: **effbot.org is taking a break** but you can find snapshots at [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200707035158/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm).